# How do I catch in C# an exception from an asynchronous method that is awaited?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, exception, async-await

I'm basically wondering how I should, in C#, catch exceptions from asynchronous methods that are waited on through the `await` keyword. Consider for example the following small console program, which most importantly contains a method called `AwaitSync`. `AwaitSync` calls `TestAsync`, which returns a Task that when executed throws an exception. I try to catch the exception in `AwaitAsync`, *but it goes unhandled*.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AwaitAsync();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task AwaitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await TestAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
        }
    }

    static Task TestAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception("Test"); });
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to go about catching the exception from the Task returned by `TestAsync`? While this example is a console program, my real life problem is within the context of of ASP.NET MVC / Web API.

**EDIT:**
Turns out the exception is getting caught, for technical reasons I just didn't notice the 'Exception caught' message before the terminal closed. In any case, Jon Skeet's answer was very valuable to my understanding of `await` and exception handling.

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't work?

Comment: When I run your code, I see "Exception caught".

Comment: It doesn't get caught for me. I'll check again.

Comment: @jishi See my edited question, it does get caught after all.

Comment: @spender You're right, it went by unnoticed in my case for technical reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code generated for the `await` expression will call `GetResult()` on the `TaskAwaiter` associated with the `Task` returned by `TestAsync`.

`GetResult` will notice that the task is faulted, fetch the *first* exception from the `AggregateException` within the task, and throw that.

The net result is that your catch block will catch the exception thrown in your task - but if you await a task which has *multiple* exceptions, you'll only see the first one unless you take special actions (there are various approaches to this).

As you're claiming the exception actually goes unhandled, it seems there's something in your code other than what you're showing - as the code you've given should certainly work, and does for me.

Comment: Thanks, will elaborate after lunch.

Comment: It turns out the exception is in fact caught, but the confirmation message isn't written out to the console before I press a key to end the program. Therefore I didn't notice the message getting printed at first. Guess asynchrony takes some getting used to :)

Comment: Thanks very much btw for your explanation of how exceptions are handled with await, very useful to my understanding.