# calling GetAsync multiple times only executes one time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I'am trying to call GetAsync multiple times in a nonblocking async function. To my surprise only the fist call gets executed. All requests are to the same domain so I figured it makes sense to reuse `HttpClient`. Why is only the first request executed and how should I rewrite the code?

```
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler(){UseProxy = false});

private static async Task NonblockingGet(string destination){
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
 var result = await client.GetAsync(destination);
 // handle result
}


private static void CallMultipleTimes(){
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url1"); // only this one is executed
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url2");
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url3");
}

//main
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
CallMultipleTimes();
mre.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Note that you don't await any of the tasks. If your intention is to run all tasks in parallel, make it explicit with `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: How do you know only the first one is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all three calls to `NonblockingGet` are executed. But on the second call, you are trying to modify the `client` (ie set the Timeout) after there was already a request started. That's not allowed and it throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception (which is silently ignored)

> This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

Thus, of course, the second and the third `client.GetAsync()` are not executed.

Move the `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);` to be the first statement in `CallMultipleTimes()` (or somewhere else where it's only executed once before the very first request) and everything will work as expected (at least for this usecase).

```
private static async Task NonblockingGet(string destination){
 // client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); // <--- remove it here
 var result = await client.GetAsync(destination);
 // handle result
}


private static void CallMultipleTimes(){
  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);  // <--- add it here
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url1"); // only this one is executed
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url2");
 NonblockingGet("domain1/url3");
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Thank you! Not related to the question.. Why do exceptions thrown in async code not propagate to the calling thread? Is wrapping every async cine try catch the only way to catch them?

Comment: Maybe these can be a starting point for your reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507895/where-to-catch-exception-in-async-code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267029/how-do-i-catch-in-c-sharp-an-exception-from-an-asynchronous-method-that-is-await

Comment: @sanjihan You need to `await` them otherwise how can they get propagated back? I suggest you take all the resulting tasks and use `await Task.WhenAll(yourTasks);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why only the first call is executed (I tried the code myself and all of them are correctly called). However usually you don't want to mix Thread Waiting with async code. And you want all your async operation to be awaited and executed inside a Task (For correct exception handling).

**That's my proposal**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseProxy = false});

async Task NonblockingGet(string destination)
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    var result = await client.GetAsync(destination);
    // handle result
}


async Task CallMultipleTimes() =>
    await Task.WhenAll(NonblockingGet("domain1/url1"), NonblockingGet("domain1/url2"), NonblockingGet("domain1/url3"));


// Main
await CallMultipleTimes();
// If you are here all 3 operations requests are completed
```

**Notes:** If you are using .Net < 6.0 you have to change your Main function signature from static void to static async Task.

Comment: Are you really sure, the location `//handle result` is reached 3 times? I don't think so, because `client.Timeout = ...` will throw an exception, when it's called again after  sending the first request, even if the requests are executed one after the other